# How can a function know which clickable textView has called it with onClick?

Tags: android, eclipse, textview, clickable

When I choose to call a function with onClick on a clickable TextView, how do I get the function to know which TextView has called it?

For example, when I have this in my MainActivity.java:

```
public void showHideData(View view)
{
    //Log.v("showHideDataA: ",  "Calling package null, local class name: " + this.getLocalClassName() + " request orientation: " + ("" + this.getRequestedOrientation()));
    if (findViewById(R.id.letterContentTextViewArrayB).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
    {
        findViewById(R.id.checkedB).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.notcheckedB).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.letterContentTextViewArrayB).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        findViewById(R.id.checkedB).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        findViewById(R.id.notcheckedB).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        findViewById(R.id.letterContentTextViewArrayB).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
} // end of showHideData(0)
```

and the following TextViews:

```
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/firstLetterTextViewArrayA"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_a_label"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="showHideData"/>
           <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/firstLetterTextViewArrayB"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/btn_b_label"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="showHideData" />
```

is there a way to get showHideData(View view) to know which TextView called it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void showHideData(View view)
{
     view.getId();
     ...
}
```

this will return the id of the `view` that was clicked. So you can use a `switch` statement

```
public void showHideData(View view)
{
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.firstLetterTextViewArrayA:
        // logic for this button
        break;
        case R.id.firstLetterTextViewArrayB:
        // logic for this button
        break;
}
```

Comment: Did this do what you needed?

Comment: I answered late because I am in Denmark!
I knew it, that somebody would know about this. Thanks a lot, you did save me a lot of aggravation and a lot of ugly code!
And I did find out that I should use case R.id.firstLetterTextViewA instead of firstLetterTextViewA...

Comment: No problem. Sorry about that typo, I guess I wrote it kind of quick. I have edited my post to reflect that. Thanks!